# How to post values using DisplayFor

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core-mvc

I can't get the values in controller from the post method used on the view and I don't know why. I saw a lot of forums and I thought that I was doing the right thing, but it doesn't seem to be the correct way to do because I can't get the values.

First I was using just the `DisplayFor` but that just shows and not pass the values then I join the `HiddenFor` to use that like an input like I saw in other forums. But the model always returns zero values.

AtribuiçãoController:

```
public IActionResult Create(List<Main> main)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model ModelsLibrary.Main
<form asp-action="Create">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label>Disciplina</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Turno</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Tipologia</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Docente</label>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Turno)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MetaDisciplina.Nome)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.MetaDisciplina.Nome)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LetraTurno)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.LetraTurno)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Tipologia.Tipo)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Tipologia.Tipo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select asp-for="Docente" asp-items="ViewBag.Docente"></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
</div>
</form>
```

**Index Method**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var Turno = new List<Turno>();

        Main main = new Main();
        main.Turno = Turno;

        ViewData["Ano"] = new SelectList(_context.AnoLetivo, "Ano", "Ano");
        return View(main);
    }
```

Hi have a problem binding the values to the controller. The method create should get values in the attributes but i don't know why and heaven don't know why the values not pass... I not pass a list to the view but i want one list in the create method.... If someone can help.

Comment: Why would you degrade performance by including a whole lot of hidden inputs, sent it to the client and sens it all back again unchanged (just get the collection again in the POST method is you need it?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your Controller. Your create method do redirect to your Index method but you don't pass your List main

I think your code should be like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Main> main = (List<Main>)TempData["yourData"];
        if (main == null)
        {
            main = new List<Main>();
        }
        return View("Index", main);
    }
    public IActionResult Create(List<Main> main)
    {
        TempData["yourData"] = main;
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

The way your want to redirect your data is called the POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern. If your want more information about it, visit this website : https://andrewlock.net/post-redirect-get-using-tempdata-in-asp-net-core/

--------------------EDIT--------------------

You have a binding problem while passing data from View to Controller. You can use an TempData in your View to pass your complete Model to your controller:

```
@model  List<WebApplication1.Models.TestObject>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ToDisplay)
}


<form action="/Home/Create" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $('form').submit(function() {
    @{ TempData["FullModel"] = Model; }
    });
</script>
```

In this exemple, i use a jquery script to create a TempData and send it to the controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<TestObject> main = (List<TestObject>)TempData["yourData"];
        if (main == null)
        {
            main = new List<TestObject>();
            main.Add(new TestObject("1"));
            main.Add(new TestObject("2"));
            main.Add(new TestObject("3"));
            main.Add(new TestObject("4"));
            main.Add(new TestObject("5"));
        }
        return View("Index", main);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<TestObject> main = (List<TestObject>)TempData["FullModel"];
        TempData["yourData"] = main;
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
}
```

Hope it was helpfull

Comment: On your "Create" POST, is List<Main> main null? if your list is null, that means your have a binding probleme while passing data from View (Index) to Controller (Create)

Comment: Yeah... The list<Main> main os null i only can get values with of docente select if use another attribute... But i don't know why came null the Main....

Comment: 2 up votes for a wrong answer that has nothing to do with the question?

Comment: How can I just pass the model like an attribute to create method?? Because that is the problem... Nothing pass